# How do you apply src_indices in promotes_inputs=[], when you have multiple promoted inputs?

Tags: openmdao

[The docs only show examples for when a component promotes a single input.](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/grouping_components/src_indices.html) How do I use src_indices to indicate that only one of my promoted inputs takes a certain slice?

```
    p.model.add_subsystem('ComputeWakePosition', ComputeWakePosition(num_wake_points_per_side=4),
                          promotes_inputs=['wake_upper_lengths',
                                           'wake_lower_lengths',
                                           'wake_upper_angles',
                                           'wake_lower_angles',
                                           'displaced_cw_coordinates'], <-- I want to specify src_indices for this input only.
                          promotes_outputs=['upper_wake_coordinates',
                                            'lower_wake_coordinates'])
```

I think I would be able to just use connect for that input, but given that everything else I've written doesn't use it, it'd be nice if there was a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function called `promotes` that you can call on your group after you've added a subsystem.  In your code above, you could remove the promotion of the `displaced_cw_coordinates` variable from your `add_subsystem` call and make a separate call something like this `p.model.promotes('ComputeWakePosition', inputs=['displaced_cw_coordinates'], src_indices=[2,4,6,8])`